# How to access the router prop in VUE

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have declared a route to which I want to pass a prop to show one or another header in my index component, but I cannot access the prop in any way ...

```
  {
    path: '/tienda/:id',
    name: 'tienda',
    component: InicioSistema,
    props: { headersistema: true, }
  },
```

In my Header.vue

```
    <div v-if="this.$route.props.headersistema">
A header...
    </div>
    <div v-else>
Show Other header..
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `this` from `v-if`. Vue already binds `this` when templating.

```html
<template>
    <div v-if="$route.props.headersistema">A header...</div>
    <div v-else>Show Other header..</div>
</template>
```

Comment: meta: { headersistema: true, }
<div v-if="$route.meta.headersistema"></div>
It work. Thanks!

Comment: if my answer helped you, please assign it as the solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    export default {
        props: ['headersistema'],
    };
</script>
```

in order to test add the below inside script:

```
 mounted() {
        if (this.headersistema){
            console.log(this.headersistema, 'headersistema')
           
        }
    },
```